# C Codes to Take string argument in Command Line Different Argument

Tags: c, linux, arguments, command

i want to make a C Program which takes 2 argument in command line.
like i want to upgrade yum via my own command like :

```
mycommand yum upgrade
```

in this, mycommand is a C compiled file and yum upgrade are arguments.
now the program will take the argument yum upgrade.
and then program will check that if argument is equals to yum upgrade then program will run this code : system("yum upgrade")

anyone can tell me how can i do this?

Comment: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { if (argc == 3 && !strcmp(argv[1], "yum") && !strcmp(argv[2], "upgrade"))  { system("yum upgrade"); } }`. This is a pure `C` question. `bash` tag should be removed.

Comment: What do you want to happen if you run `mycommand ls -l`? Should it run `ls -l` or say "Sorry, arguments are not equal to 'yum upgrade'"?

Comment: @thatotherguy it will show argument not equal to yum upgrade